# How can this object change its volume based on the view mode I'm in?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I'm currently making a image based on a photo with CGI elements added to it. Therefore, I'm playing with holdouts and shadow catchers. But I'm having this really weird issue where the ground (that's defining the shape of the snow by clipping into it) seems to change its shape whether I'm rendering it/looking at it in rendered view or looking at it in any other view mode.

[image]

In the pictures, the ground has not its shadow catcher or holdout enable. Enabling one or the other or both doesn't change anything. What does change something however is switching to Eevee which confuses me even further.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: if you are using a subd modifier, make sure the level viewport and render value are the same

Comment: Yeah, absolutely, didn't thought of that! Nonetheless, that's not the source of the issue as the subdivision levels of the snow are matching and the ground doesn't have any modifiers.

Comment: are you using displacement on your mesh? Since material preview uses eevee, it can be different depending on your material properties if you render with cycles

Comment: I do use displacement on the snow, yes. So the solution is to modify the shape of the snow under the rendered view?

Comment: Yes because Eevee doesn't support displacement with shaders. You can use it with a displace modifier tho